# javascript - multiple moving walls

Tags: javascript, web, web-deployment, game-development

I am making a game like flappy bird , the only difference is that the bird moves by using the mouse pointer location any where on the canvas. So for the obstacle i made walls but the walls are appearing in a bunch. I am not able to make walls that appear on regular interval in the canvas .

Required image :-

i am getting this :-

```js
var context;
var screenWidth;
var screenHeight;
var ball;
var wall = [];
var gameStatus;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

var running = false;
var raf;

gameIntialize();
gameDraw();

function Ball() {
  this.radius = 16;
  this.x = 25;
  this.y = screenHeight / 2;
  this.ballDraw = function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, 16, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
  }
};


function Wall() {
  this.thickness = 10;
  this.wallPositionY = screenHeight;
  this.wallPositionX = screenWidth;

  this.spacing = 0;

  if (this.wallPositionY > 400 && this.wallPositionY <= 500) {
    this.spacing = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
  } else if (this.wallPositionY > 500) {
    this.spacing = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100) + 100);
  } else {
    this.spacing = 45;
  }

  this.heightFromTheTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.wallPositionY / 6 - 3 / 4 * this.wallPositionY) + this.wallPositionY);
  this.heightFromTheBottom = this.wallPositionY - (this.heightFromTheTop + this.spacing);
  this.speed = 6;

  this.draw = function() {

    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.fillRect(this.wallPositionX, 0, this.thickness, this.heightFromTheTop);
    context.fillRect(this.wallPositionX, this.wallPositionY - this.heightFromTheBottom, this.thickness, this.heightFromTheBottom);
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.wallPositionX = this.wallPositionX - this.speed;
  }

  this.offscreen = function() {
    if (this.wallPositionX < -this.thickness) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  this.newWall = function() {
    if (this.wallPositionX < screenWidth / 2) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};


function gameIntialize() {
  var canvass = document.getElementById('canvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

  canvas.width = screenWidth;
  canvas.height = screenHeight;

  ball = new Ball();
  wall.push(new Wall());


  // window.addEventListener('resize', resizeScreen, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (!running) {
      ball.x = e.clientX;
      ball.y = e.clientY;

    }
  });


}

function gameDraw() {
  context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

  ball.ballDraw();

  for (var i = wall.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    wall[i].draw();
    wall[i].update();

    if (wall[i].offscreen()) {
      wall.splice(i, 1);
    }
    var test_interval = setInterval(function() {
      wall.push(new Wall());
    }, 5000);

  }


  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(gameDraw);

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>game-run</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>


</html>
```

What is wrong with this code? I appreciate any help!

Comment: The thing wrong with the code is available in the error console.

Comment: There is no error in the console

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: resizeScreen is not defined`

Comment: I see it: `  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeScreen, false);`: resizeScreen isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: What does this have to do with `web-deployment`?

Comment: you can comment out that line, it is to check if the web browser has been resized or not , it doesn't effect the rest of the code

Comment: Not the problem, but kittens cry every time someone uses `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }`... just use `return condition;` :).

Comment: I know my IDE would cry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setInterval creation code is sitting inside your game loop.

That means you're creating a new 5 second interval for EVERY FRAME!

Take it out of there and things should be fine.

Modified snippet:

```js
var context;
var screenWidth;
var screenHeight;
var ball;
var wall = [];
var gameStatus;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

var running = false;
var raf;

gameIntialize();
gameDraw();

function Ball() {
  this.radius = 16;
  this.x = 25;
  this.y = screenHeight / 2;
  this.ballDraw = function() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(this.x, this.y, 16, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill();
  }
};


function Wall() {
  this.thickness = 10;
  this.wallPositionY = screenHeight;
  this.wallPositionX = screenWidth;

  this.spacing = 0;

  if (this.wallPositionY > 400 && this.wallPositionY <= 500) {
    this.spacing = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 50) + 50);
  } else if (this.wallPositionY > 500) {
    this.spacing = Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 100) + 100);
  } else {
    this.spacing = 45;
  }

  this.heightFromTheTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.wallPositionY / 6 - 3 / 4 * this.wallPositionY) + this.wallPositionY);
  this.heightFromTheBottom = this.wallPositionY - (this.heightFromTheTop + this.spacing);
  this.speed = 6;

  this.draw = function() {

    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.fillRect(this.wallPositionX, 0, this.thickness, this.heightFromTheTop);
    context.fillRect(this.wallPositionX, this.wallPositionY - this.heightFromTheBottom, this.thickness, this.heightFromTheBottom);
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.wallPositionX = this.wallPositionX - this.speed;
  }

  this.offscreen = function() {
    if (this.wallPositionX < -this.thickness) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  this.newWall = function() {
    if (this.wallPositionX < screenWidth / 2) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
};


function gameIntialize() {
  var canvass = document.getElementById('canvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  screenHeight = window.innerHeight;

  canvas.width = screenWidth;
  canvas.height = screenHeight;

  ball = new Ball();
  wall.push(new Wall());


  // window.addEventListener('resize', resizeScreen, false);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (!running) {
      ball.x = e.clientX;
      ball.y = e.clientY;

    }
  });


}

function gameDraw() {
  context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);

  ball.ballDraw();

  for (var i = wall.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

    wall[i].draw();
    wall[i].update();

    if (wall[i].offscreen()) {
      wall.splice(i, 1);
    }

  }



  raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(gameDraw);

}

var test_interval = setInterval(function() {
  wall.push(new Wall());
}, 1500);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>game-run</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

</body>
<script src="game.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: It's my pleasure. Good luck with the game!